# Can heat energy be transferred through matter by radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

My hypothesis is that it is not possible for heat to be transferred this way because it seems that any matter would simply experience a temperature increase instead of allowing heat to pass through.

Despite this, though, I am uncertain since beta radiation (among other types) seem to be able to pass through solid materials like human skin, for instance.

Comment: good to study this  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the opacity and density of the matter at the wavelength of the radiation.

Examples where energy can pass through, and heat something on the other side:
Radio waves passing through walls.
Infrared light from the Sun passing through the atmosphere.
Light passing through the glass of a greenhouse, heating the inside.
Microwave energy in your microwave passing through glass or tupperware.
X-ray and gamma rays passing through tissue and other solid matter.

I offer these examples to show you that density of matter, opacity of matter, and wavelength of light are all diverse, leading to diverse behavior.